# How to calcualte prior Year Cumulative QTD sales

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the prior year cumulate QTD sales.

Input:[image]

expected output : [image]

```
;with Data AS (
    select 2021 as [year], 1 as [Quarter] , 1 as SalesID,'1/29/2021' AS Date, 45 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION 
    select 2021 as [year], 2 as [Quarter] , 1 as SalesID,'4/26/2022' AS Date, 100 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION 
    select 2021 as [year], 3 as [Quarter] , 1 as SalesID,'8/29/2021' AS Date, 100 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION 
    select 2021 as [year], 4 as [Quarter] , 1 as SalesID,'11/26/2022' AS Date,50 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION
    select 2022 as [year], 1 as [Quarter] , 1 as SalesID,'1/25/2022' AS Date,100 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION 
    select 2022 as [year], 2 as [Quarter] , 1 as SalesID,'5/22/2022' AS Date,200 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION 
    select 2022 as [year], 3 as [Quarter] , 1 as SalesID,'7/16/2022' AS Date,300 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION 
    select 2022 as [year], 4 as [Quarter] , 1 as SalesID,'12/16/2022' AS Date,400 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION--
    select 2021 as [year], 3 as [Quarter] , 2 as SalesID,'1/26/2021' AS Date, 10 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION 
    select 2021 as [year], 4 as [Quarter] , 2 as SalesID,'12/15/2021' AS Date, 15 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION 
    select 2022 as [year], 1 as [Quarter] , 2 as SalesID,'1/10/2022' AS Date, 20 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION 
    select 2022 as [year], 2 as [Quarter] , 2 as SalesID,'4/10/2022' AS Date, 20 AS SalesAmt 
    UNION 
    select 2022 as [year], 4 as [Quarter] , 2 as SalesID,'10/24/2022' AS Date, 20 AS salesAmt 
    ) 
     select [Year],[quarter],[Date],SalesID     
    ,SUM(SalesAmt) OVER (Partition by [Year],SalesId order by [quarter]) As YTDSales
     ,LAG(SalesAmt,4) OVER (  Partition by SalesId order by [Year]) As PriorCumulativeQTDSales 
     from  data a
```

Issue: I am not able to get the PriorCumulativeQTDSales, Any pointers on how to fix my query please ?

Note: For 2022 Q1 for SalesId (1), PriorCumulativeQTDsales is previous year Quarter1 sales which is 45.
For 2022 Q2, PriorCumulativeQTDsales is sum of previous year Quarter1 sales + Quarter 2 sales
For 2022 Q3, PriorCumulativeQTDsales is sum of previous year Quarter1 sales + Quarter 2  + Quarter 3 sales

In case of salesId (2), since quarters are missing (2021 quarter1 , Quarter2 and 2022 quarter3), PriorCumulativeQTDsales is sum of previous year(2021) Quarter 3 sales + Quarter 4  sales and it should be populated in 2022 Quarter 4 as 2022 quarter 3 is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case it's easier not to use LAG but to do a self join:

```sql
SELECT  [Year],[quarter],[Date],SalesID     
,   SUM(SalesAmt) OVER (Partition BY [Year],SalesId ORDER BY [quarter]) AS YTDSales
,   ISNULL(priorCumQTDSales, 0) AS PriorCumulativeQTDSales 
FROM    data a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  sum(SalesAmt) AS priorCumQTDSales
    FROM    data prev
    WHERE   prev.salesID = a.SalesID
    AND prev.year = a.year -1
    AND prev.quarter <= a.quarter
) prev
```

Or a subquery if you swing that way:

```sql
SELECT  [Year],[quarter],[Date],SalesID     
,   SUM(SalesAmt) OVER (Partition BY [Year],SalesId ORDER BY [quarter]) AS YTDSales
,   ISNULL((
    SELECT  sum(SalesAmt) AS priorCumQTDSales
    FROM    data prev
    WHERE   prev.salesID = a.SalesID
    AND prev.year = a.year -1
    AND prev.quarter <= a.quarter
) , 0) AS PriorCumulativeQTDSales 
FROM    data a
```

Comment: Thank you. Subquery option is working as expected.